# parsing Array in half

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Why does this array parse not work?

```js
var input = [ 'sam 99912222',
  'tom 11122222',
  'harry 12299933',
  'sam',
  'edward',
  'harry' ];

var numItems = 3;
console.log(input);

var phoneNames  = [];
var searchNames = [];
var phoneBook   = [];

for (i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
    phoneNames.push(input[i]);
    var j = i + numItems;
    searchNames.push(input[j]);
}
console.log("phoneNames: " + phoneNames);
console.log("searchNames: " + searchNames);
```

Outputs:

```
[ 'sam 99912222',
  'tom 11122222',
  'harry 12299933',
  'sam',
  'edward',
  'harry' ]
phoneNames: sam 99912222,tom 11122222,harry 12299933
searchNames: ,,
```

Why is searchNames not being filled with values?

Comment: How large is your input array ? Is the index j greater than the size of the input array ?

Comment: If you click the "Run code snippet" button, you'll see that the output is as expected. Either your actual input or your actual code is something else.

Comment: check the snippet, searchNames are filled

Comment: right on @JJJ - yep, it does run here perfectly.  the same code was not filling that array in a different compiler.  interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the assumption, that your input array looks like the code below, your solution works perfectly for me. I took the exact same code snippet like you did with adding the input at the beginning.

```
var input = [ 'sam 99912222',
               'tom 11122222',
               'harry 12299933',
               'sam',
               'edward',
               'harry' 
          ];
```

This leads to the following output:

```
phoneNames: sam 99912222,tom 11122222,harry 12299933
searchNames: sam,edward,harry
```

In addition, if you always have this type of data structure (an even array length), and take the half of your array length as `numItems`, you should not have any trouble with out of bound exceptions. For a dynamic iteration value `i`, just take the half of the array size:

```
var numItems = input.length / 2;
```

Here is my complete code I just ran:

```
        var input = [ 'sam 99912222',
          'tom 11122222',
          'harry 12299933',
          'sam',
          'edward',
          'harry' 
        ];          

        var numItems = input.length / 2;

        console.log(input);

        var phoneNames  = [];
        var searchNames = [];
        var phoneBook   = [];

        for (i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
            phoneNames.push(input[i]);
            var j = i + numItems;
            searchNames.push(input[j]);
        }
        console.log("phoneNames: " + phoneNames);
        console.log("searchNames: " + searchNames);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var input = [ 'sam 99912222',
  'tom 11122222',
  'harry 12299933',
  'sam',
  'edward',
  'harry' ];

var numItems = 6;

var phoneNames  = [];
var searchNames = [];
var phoneBook   = [];

for (i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
    var val = input[i].split(" ");
    phoneNames.push(val[0]);
    searchNames.push(val[1]);
}
console.log("phoneNames: ", phoneNames);
console.log("searchNames: ", searchNames);
```

Comment: result will be 
phoneNames: sam,tom,harry,sam,edward,harry
searchNames: 99912222,11122222,12299933,,,